PHPMailer taking too long with external domain smtp
I run the phpmailer smtp for sending mails. Everything was working fine with old hosting, but after transferd to vps it stop working for external domain smtp.
if i use phpmailer with my own domain mail settings its working (however mail not sending but phpmailer runs successfully.) but if i use external domain smtp like my another domain hosted to different company or gmail or yahoo, it take too long to load and then got error Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
Can anyone help why its taking too much time and connection error only for external domains.. ?

What happened when you did what the docs say?

@Synchro I dont know what is the problem actually because its not throwing any error.. so what exact problem is i dont understand. When i configure the vps first time it was working fine for 2 hrs. After that it stops working dont know why.. today is 8 days but couldnt figure out. Even from server cant send mail to external domain it send only internal domain of server. What should be the problem? Any guess?

Sounds like your hosting provider spotted you sending lots of email and blocked your outbound SMTP, all of which you could diagnose using the suggestions in the docs. If you have connection-level problems, you need SMTPDebug = 3 to see them in PHPMailer debug output, however, a blocked connection doesn't provide much info because nothing really happens.
